# What to do if I get Cloudflare 403?

Tags: node.js, proxy, http-status-code-403, openai-api, telegraf

I have a bot written on node.js and telegraf: ^4.12.2 using openai api. Everything was fine until last week. When on my VPS server and all my local machines, instead of response, I started receiving Cloudflare html markup: “Sorry, you have been blocked.” What methods can be used to solve the problem?

For example:
if I make a request to "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", I get "Sorry, you have been blocked
You are unable to access api.openai.com" in html markup"...

Link to bot source: https://github.com/BLazzeD21/Node.js-ChatGPT-Bot

I tried to use a proxy, but still couldn't get access.